# A multi-platform way to access jar located resources in java

Tags: java, file, embedded-resource

I need some code that could get an `InputStream` from a resource stored in some path into a jar file, this is the test code:

```
  String res =File.separatorChar+ "folder"+File.separatorChar+"file.txt";
  InputStream is = ReadRes.class.getResourceAsStream(res);
  System.out.println(is);
```

Into my jar I have the directory folder/file.txt, in linux it works but on Windows I get a null value for `is`  . What should I do?

Comment: in **linux** it works but on **linux** i get a null value? !! I think your question needs revision, one of them should be windows, I guess ;)

Comment: Dont use file.speratorchar. Simply use /

Comment: replacing File.separatorChar with / i corrected, i thought that File.separatorChar was a platform-independent way to specify path separator, i was wrong. Thanks

Comment: If you read _files_ you should use `File.spearatorChar` to have a platform-independent code. But here youre giving a path to `getResourceAsStream`, which works differently. It expects path separated by `/`.

Answer (score 4):

Always use `/` when fetching the resource.

The resource is not a `File`, and the path is represented by an `URL` which always has forward slashes.